# Controller class for dynamic Javafx view

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javafx

I am new to **Javafx** and **Spring** and making a simple desktop app to load data from **database** and show it in a **tableview**. I have put all my code in a single class which creates the **views** and **load** the table and handles adding new rows and editing of the table. But I am confused how to split this class into **Controller** and **View** parts (**like MVC pattern**). My **class** looks like this:

```
package com.waq;

// some imports

@Component
public class PartsView{

    private TableView table;
    TextField desc;
    Label title;
    Button save;
    GridPane grid;

    @Autowired
    private PartService partService;

    public PartsView(){
        createTable();
        grid = new GridPane();
        save = new Button();
        save.setText("Save");
        save.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            // Some logic
        }
    }


    private void loadData() {
        List<Part> parts = partService.findAll();
        if(parts.size() > 0) {
            ObservableList<Part> observableArrayList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(parts);
            table.setItems( observableArrayList);
        }
        else
            table.setPlaceholder(new Label("No data to show."));
    }

    private void saveData(){
        // save record.
    }


    private void createTable(){
        CustomTableColumn<Part,String> idColumn = new CustomTableColumn<Part,String>("id");
        idColumn.setPercentWidth(10);
        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Part,String>("id"));

        CustomTableColumn<Part,String> descCol = new CustomTableColumn<Part,String>("description");
        descCol.setPercentWidth(50);
        descCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Part,String>("description"));

        table.getColumns().addAll(idColumn,descCol);

        grid.getChildren().add(table);
    }

}
```

I saw other examples but mostly they were generating the view in **fxml** files and then get the view object using **@FXML** annotation. But here in my case I'm creating view objects in the class. If I separate this class in view and controller classes, then how I will define the action lets say for the save button and how I will access my table view in the controller class?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you create custom JavaFx `Node` as a `Bean`, you can `@Autowired` it to controller, but you have to add one to `Node` which represent your custom `Node`.

You have two ways:

1. `extends` your class of `Node`(or heirs of `Node`)(look at example)
2. return from your class`root-Node` which contains others nodes

Example:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype") //If you want to reuse component `@Scope("prototype")`
public class PartsView  extends GridPane{ 
  ...
  public void init(){
    getChildren().add(table);
  }

}
```

Controller should look like:

```
public class TestController implements Initializable  {

  @FXML //StackPane as example
  private StackPane stackPane; //injecting before constructor, when you load .fxml
  @Autowired
  private PartsView partsView; //injecting when you load spring-context


  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // initialize fields marked @FXML annotation.
    // method initialize triggering after constructor
  }
}
```

The mane problem is that you have to add your custom `Node` to context before initialization of `Controller`. You can write `Configuration` to solve it:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({
    "you.node.packege",
 })
public class TestConfig{

@Lazy                                  //depends on your case
@Bean
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE) //depends on your case
public ControlFx<TabPane, PlanningController> testViewFx() throws IOException {
    return loadView("/view/TestLayout.fxml");
}


    private <V extends Node, C extends Initializable> ControlFx<V,C> loadView(String url) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(url));
        return  new ViewFx<>(loader.load(), loader.getController());
    }
 }
```

ControlFx class:

```
public class ControlFx<N extends Node ,C extends Initializable>  {
    private final N view;
    private final C controller;

    public ControlFx(N view, C controller) {
        this.view = view;
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public N getView() {
        return view;
    }

    public C getController() {
        return controller;
    }

}
```

> I separate this class in view and controller classes, then how I will define the action lets say for the save button and how I will access my table view in the controller class?

You can write `facade`-method into you custom class:

```
public  void setOnActionSaveButton(EventHandler<ActionEvent> value){
    save.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
        // Some logic
    }
}
```

> I am generating all the view with code, without any fxml file. In that case how it will work?

Use `@Controller` annotation (extends of `@Component`) with `@PostConstruct` annotation or use `@Autowired` with constructor(or any `init` way):

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

   private StackPane stackPane;
   // @Autowired
   private PartsView  partsView;

   @Autowired
   public TestController (PartsView  partsView){
      ...
      stackPane.getChildren().add(partsView)
   }

   // @PostConstruct
   // private void beanPostConstruct() {
   //     stackPane.getChildren().add(partsView);
   // }
}
```

> In your 2nd and 3rd code snippet, you mentioned loading fxml file but I dont have any.

You have to init spring-context at first. I used `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`:

```
public abstract class AbstractJavaFxApplication extends Application {

    private static String[] savedArgs;
    protected AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        context =  new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(configurations());
        context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        super.stop();
        context.close();
    }

    protected static void launchApp(Class<? extends AbstractJavaFxApplication> clazz, String[] args) {
        AbstractJavaFxApplication.savedArgs = args;
        Application.launch(clazz, savedArgs);
    }

    protected abstract Class<?>[] configurations();
}
```

Impl.:

```
public class ReportApp extends AbstractJavaFxApplication {

    public final double PRIMARY_WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500;
    public final double PRIMARY_WINDOW_WIDTH = 500;

    @Value("${ui.title:JavaFX приложение}")
    private String windowTitle;

    @Autowired
    private RootLayoutController controller;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle(windowTitle);
        stage.setScene(
                new Scene(
                        controller.getPane(),
                        PRIMARY_WINDOW_WIDTH,
                        PRIMARY_WINDOW_HEIGHT
                )
        );
        stage.setResizable(true);
        stage.centerOnScreen();
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launchApp(ReportApp.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] configurations() {
        return new Class<?>[]{
            Config.class
        };
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"components", "controllers"})
public class Config {

    @Bean
    ...
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class RootLayoutController {

    private StackPane stackPane;
    @Autowired
    private PartsView partsView;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        stackPane = new StackPane();
        stackPane.getChildren().add(partsView);
    }

    public Pane getPane(){
        return stackPane;
    }        
}
```

Comment: I am generating all the view with code, without any fxml file. In that case how it will work?

Comment: In your 2nd and 3rd code snippet, you mentioned loading fxml file but I dont have any.

Comment: @Waqar Ahmed look at examples